# Not showing Custom cell in tableview with firebase

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Xcode and Firebas*. When you click the post button it saves the data to Firebase and takes you to the `UITableView`. But for some reason, `UITableViewCell` isn't showing. I don't know why the custom cell isn't showing. Custom class is created for the cell and I linked it to the identifier. The content on the cell is a `UILabel`. Why isn't the `UITableViewCell` showing the data from Firebase?

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class TableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var OpenPost: UIButton!

    let storiesRef = Database.database().reference().child("People").child("HomeFeed").child("Posts")
    var stories = [Story]()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // download stories
        storiesRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.stories.removeAll()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let childSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
                let story = Story(snapshot: childSnapshot)
                print(story)
                self.stories.insert(story, at: 0)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return stories.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Story Cell", for: indexPath) as! StoryTableviewcell
        let story = stories[indexPath.row]

        cell.story = story

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: check your "Story Cell" identifier it is correct check Alphabet

Comment: Where's your post buttion click method?

Comment: firebase and tableview has no connection for above issue, i think you made minor mistake at some place and that you only can track what is issue. put break point and check **stories.count** value.